# Bounding the $H^s$ norm of the product of two functions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Is it true that for $f,g \in H^s$, we have
$$ \lVert fg \rVert_{H^s} \leq \lVert f \rVert_{H^s} \lVert g \rVert_{H^s}?$$
I *think* this is what the author is using on page 651 in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220132092_The_Generalized_Hunter-Saxton_System) in the step
$$ \lVert (\sigma^2 - \rho^2) \rVert_s \leq \lVert \sigma + \rho \rVert_s \lVert \sigma - \rho \rVert_s,$$
but I have never seen this type of inequality.

Comment: There is the so-called Sobolev product theorem. Maybe it is this theorem that is used. Are you familiar with this result?

Comment: This theorem appears to have a constant in the front of the right-hand side, though?

Comment: Yes, but maybe the constant is 1 in the case considered in the paper. However, as said, I am not entirely sure. This is the only type of inequality considering the product of functions in Sobolev spaces I know.